# dynamic connection string in asp.net mvc app and Linq2Sql for multitenant app and forms authentication

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql, sql-server-2008, forms-authentication, saas

so I'm developing a SAAS application using asp.net mvc SQL server 2008 and Linq2SQL I've a master db where I'll store information about clients like name subdomain/hostname information and other stuff and I'll use one database per client for the actual client data,

what is the best way to generate and use the connection string for each individual db the connection string will be based on each customer domain so I could hard code it into master db at customer creation and create the DataContext based on that? any flaws in this strategy?

I am also using forms authentication and it will be built into each clients own db so do I've add anything dynamically to the configuration? as currently the authentication/membership is driven by connection string inside the web.config file

Answer (score 0):

You should probably have a table in a centralized master db that includes the database connection information for each client. Then in your SAAS application, any time you are instantiating the data context, instead of using the default parameterless constructor, use the constructor overload that takes the connection string you stored in the centralized database for that client. The context shouldn't be kept alive between requests, so you shouldn't have a problem with cross page requests across multiple clients.

Comment: thanks any comments on Forms Authentication specially how to deal with role manager providers are added in the form of connection string?

Comment: for example <roleManager enabled="true">
   <providers>
    <clear />
    <add connectionStringName="abc">